# Spring Web Flow: How do I pass values from one flow to another flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a Java web application using spring web flow.

How do I pass values from one flow to another flow?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <persistence-context />

    <var name="editBean" class="jp.co.anicom.domain.User" />
    <var name="deleteBean" class="jp.co.anicom.domain.User" />
    <var name="authorityBean" class="jp.co.anicom.domain.Authority" />


    <on-start>
        <set name="flowScope.username" value="requestParameters.username" />
    </on-start>

    <action-state id="queryAll">
        <evaluate expression="employeeAction.GetAuthority(flowScope.username)"
            result="authorityBean" />
        <transition to="editForm" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="editForm" model="editBean" view="../xhtml/framework/edit">
        <transition on="editButton" to="validateAccount" />
        <transition on="delete" to="getId" />
        <transition on="back" to="editSuccessful" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="validateAccount">
        <evaluate expression="employeeAction.GetEmployee(flowScope.username, oldPassword)"
            result="editBean" />
        <transition to="checkUserAccount" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="getId">
        <evaluate expression="employeeAction.GetEmployee(flowScope.username)"
            result="deleteBean" />
        <transition to="deleteUser" />
    </action-state>

    <decision-state id="checkUserAccount">
        <if test="editBean == null" then="queryAll"
            else="confirmPassword" />
    </decision-state>

    <decision-state id="confirmPassword">
        <if test="newPassword.equals(confirmPassword)" then="editUser1"
            else="queryAll" />
    </decision-state>

    <action-state id="editUser1">
        <set name="editBean.password" value="newPassword" />
        <transition to="editUser2" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="editUser2">
        <evaluate
            expression="employeeAction.editEmployee(editBean, authorityBean.authority)" />
        <transition to="editSuccessful" />
    </action-state>

    <action-state id="deleteUser">
        <evaluate expression="employeeAction.deleteEmployee(deleteBean)" />
        <transition to="editSuccessful" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="editSuccessful"
        view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/admin_main.do" commit="true" />
    <end-state id="displayError" view="../xhtml/framework/displayError" />
    <end-state id="dummy1" view="../xhtml/framework/dummy" />

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on-exception="java.lang.Exception" to="displayError" />
    </global-transitions>

</flow>
```

I am having a problem with the edit functionality here. In my edit page I have username, oldpassword, newpassword and confirm password fields.

First in validateAccount state I check if the username and oldpassword exists in the database, if it it doesn't exist I forward it to queryall state.

If it exists I check if the new password and confirmpassword values are the same, if they are the same I proceed with the editing.

If not I return again to queryAll.

QueryAll state gets the authority of the user to populate it in the form upon re-displaying the page. When I leave the password fields blank and the first time I click edit button It throws a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your two flows as subflows and then the data in each flow should be available in the parent and the other subflows.

> Mapping data to the subflow happens
>   before the subflow session is started.
>   Mapping data from the subflow back to
>   the parent flow is done when the
>   subflow completes and the parent flow
>   session resumes.